# Unable to start Redis server due to configuration file error

Tags: redis

I am just installed redis serve by following link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-redis

when I run sudo ./install_server.sh

*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
Reading the configuration file, at line 81

> > > 'protected-mode yes'
> > >       Bad directive or wrong number of arguments
> > >       ERROR: Failed starting service.... Aborting!

How can I fix it.

Comment: How about showing us lines 70-90 of your config file?

Comment: Why can't you install Redis from `apt-get install redis-server`?

Comment: It's works... thanks @bhushan

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same issue...

This is probably because you had an old version installed that is not compatible with `protected-mode yes` directive. In my own case 2.4.8, than is not compatible with rejson; and I was installing 4.0.1 version (rejson compatible).

So I've had to do previously `apt-get remove redis-server` and `make install` again; now you are ready to execute `sudo ./install_server.sh` and it should be fine now.

If you do `apt-get install redis-server`, it could be good solution as @bhushan commented, but you won't be sure enough to install the last stable version.